# How to make ONE code for clicking on a random image and open that image in another div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website with multiple images with different classes and I already have a code for clicking on a **specific** image and open it in a new fixed div, but I don't want to rewrite that code for each image on the page. Does anybody know how to make one code for **all** images on the page?

The code I already have is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.ancesters").click(function(){
        $("div.ancesters").fadeIn("slow");
        $("img.none").click(function(){
            $("div.ancesters").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

But this is just the code to view **one** div with image.

Here is the HTML code: http://jsfiddle.net/W56dL/ (it isn't in English, but that doesn't matter... I hope...

And the result: http://jsfiddle.net/xdUY5/embedded/result/

Comment: Yes but you need to show some HTML, or are we to guess?

Comment: will you only have one fixed div on the page, and each image goes into that div on click, and then remove the previous image from that div and put it back where it was?

Comment: I want to show a div with an image in it on click

Comment: Read about `this` - http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("img").click(function(){
        $("div.ancesters .big").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
        $("div.ancesters").fadeIn("slow");  
    });

    $("img.none").click(function(){
        $("div.ancesters").fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W56dL/2/)

Comment: Could you explain it? (especialy that .attr) I'm rreally not good in jquery.

Comment: So, if I understand it well (I don't think I do) you'll now set the "src" attribute of .big to the "src" attribute it had?

Comment: When you click on an image the script set this image's src to .big image.

Comment: Thank you. But why is there a strange square if you hide the div that hides itself later?

Comment: Oh, I see. It's the page that shows "X". Is there a way to delete that? It's very annoying if there is an image (with a cross for example) that shows itself large on the screen.

Comment: I've sold the problem myself. Thanks